# How to calculate camera ray position for use with XMVector3Unproject(), DirectX11?

Tags: directx, directx-11, raycasting

I'm trying to create a ray-casting camera in DirectX11 using XMVector3Unproject().  From my understanding, I will be passing in the (Vector3)position of the pixel on the near plane, and in separate call, a corresponding position on the far plane.  Then I would subtract these vectors to get the direction of the ray. The origin would then be the Unprojected coordinate on the near plane. My problem here is calculating the origin of the ray to be passed in.

Example

```
    // assuming screenHeight and screenWidth are the number of pixels.
    const uint32_t screenHeight = 768;
    const uint32_t screenWidth = 1024;

    struct Ray
    {
        XMFLOAT3 origin;
        XMFLOAT3 direction;
    };

    Ray rays[screenWidth * screenHeight];

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < screenHeight; ++i)
    {
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < screenWidth; ++j)
        {
            // 1. ***calculate and store the current pixel position on the near plane***
            // 2. ***calculate the corresponding point on the far plane***
            // 3. ***pass both positions separately into XMVector3Unproject() (2 total calls to the function)***
            // 4. ***store the returned vectors' difference into rays[i * screenWidth + j].direction***
            // 5. ***store the near plane pixel position's returned vector into rays[i * screenWidth + j].origin***
        }
    }
```

Hopefully I'm understanding this correctly.  Any help in determining the ray origins, or corrections would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.transformation.xmvector3unproject(v=vs.85).aspx), the `XMVector3Unproject` function gives you the coordinates of a ray you have provided in camera space (Normalized-device coordinates), in object space (given your model matrix).

To generate your camera rays, you consider your camera pinhole (all the light passes through one point, which is your camera `(0, 0, 0)`, then you choose your ray direction. Let say you want to generate `W*H` camera rays, your loop might look like this

```
Vector3 ray_origin = Vector3(0, 0, 0);
for (float x = -1.f; x <= 1.f; x += 2.f / W) {
    for (float y = -1.f; y <= 1.f; y += 2.f / H) {
        Vector3 ray_direction = Normalize(Vector3(x, y, -1.f)) - ray_origin;
        Vector3 ray_in_model = Unproject(ray_direction, 0.f, 0.f, 
                                         width, height, znear, zfar, 
                                         proj, view, model);
    }
}
```

You might also want to have a look at [this link](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-generating-camera-rays) which sounds interesting